# How to use typeof in function parameter and force correct variance

Tags: typescript, typeof

Lets have simple class hierarchy and the list of instances. I want to filter items from the list of instances by the class.

There are multiple issues:

- can not use `typeof T` syntax. How to write it?
- can not mark `T` as `out` variance - of course I do not want to instantiate anything in the method, but only return instances of `T`. How to tell it to TS?

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends A {
}

function filterByClass<out T extends A>(cls: typeof T, list: A[]): T[]
{
  return list.filter((item) => item instanceof T);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoAvq1pIwELQFMAPAFwIDsATGeZdTFbKaAYUNIurkVQxVQBmAV3LASASwD25aAPEgyAJ1wBPFuCgAeSUJLQAKuzJUaAPgAUoCAC5oJFQAcCkgQYA00EOIglbsANoAugCUtvpBqHTQ0IoEJEKKMl4+AHRyCgSK5ubiZAC2wdAAvKbQuQR5ZeQ+YKLOrvrBANy8qEA)

---

Edit:

The answer (from Adrian Kokot) worked until I realized that unfortunately I made the example "too simple". In reality there are constructors with parameters, more like this:

```
class B extends A {
  constructor(pb: any) {
    super();
  }
}

class C extends A {
  constructor(pc: any) {
    super();
  }
}
```

Using [modified playground from the anwer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQBfJTSRgIWgUwA8AXPAOwBMZ5lppgB7UiIgJwFdgj6WAKABwBGALmhhSATwCUiJLVoQ2fPL0kBuWdDRoM4KNADC+YmUpwZtBk1YcuvPsBFip5uQqUr1tLekvNR0AF5oUjwAdzgeNQxGPwFA4LDobB4ARijfIjp4kPD9VKjoq1EWFniAbTAAGmgBauAAXXUkADM2Uk4AS0ZoZo6QEhZscX1dCAAeABUjEgoqAD4eUAgRHOhIwLnoCeqQDuYRWDL6yREJo5cWPCI2FlJoXeYAOl7+5R4eDpIAWxPoT7wvn8YFMApt-oCOlYxMA8PRmnQQBAotoMsUWIYgi8BkMRlgePpqmASpIfDF6CA8I8QPQAOY8InotRAA), the problem with variance emerges:

```
const a = new A();
const b = new B(1);
const c = new C(1);

const arrC = filterByClass(C, arr);
```

```
Argument of type 'typeof C' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => C'.
  Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'new (pc: any) => C' is not assignable to type 'new () => C'.
```

Comment: `cls: typeof T` should just be `cls: T`. And `<out T extends A>` is invalid syntax. It should just be `<T, A>` if I look at what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Variance annotations only work with generic types but not with generic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can specify the first argument as a constructor, so you will be able to pass the class name.
2. You can use `is` operator as a return type in filter method, to tell typescript, that item is instanceof the passed class.

Possible solution:

```js
function filterByClass<T extends A>(cls: new () => T, list: A[]): T[]
{
  return list.filter((item): item is T => item instanceof cls);
}

filterByClass(C, [new A(), new B(), new C()]); // returns C[];
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQBfJTSRgIWgUwA8AXPAOwBMZ5k0NwpoBhfYsyuRVdYAe1IiLQw0ALzRSeAO5wAFAEoA3Bj4DoAI1Hip0bPKW9+g4JonTGe7isFgATjc0BtMABo1z4AF0lSAGYBXUmAiAEs+aB9gkBIbbABPRnoIAB4AFRYSCioAPhlQCAAuLWl5USzoFOdoEGCBQtgHDzlClIakZGhoGzwiPxtSKpqiADoIqLwbGRlgkgBbJuhpvBmFmDSRMsXl4MMwQLweH2g8xS5lQyE7ZjFR6LiErBlGStsbOUt+HhA8IZAeAHMZC9GIogA)

---

#### Answer to edit:

To use classes that have different constructors, you can just add `...args: any[]` to the first argument:

```js
function filterByClass<T extends A>(cls: new (...args: any[]) => T, list: A[]): T[]
{
  return list.filter((item): item is T => item instanceof cls);
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQBfJTSRgIWgUwA8AXPAOwBMZ5lppgB7UiIgJwFdgj6WAKABwBGALmhhSATwCUiJLVoQ2fPL0kBuWdDRpMUaAGF8xMpTgzaDJqw5defYCLFSzchUpXraW9BeajoAXmhSPAB3OB41DEZfAQCg0OhsHgBGSJ8iOjjgsL0UyKjLURYWOIBtMAAaAQrgAF11JAAzNlJOAEtGaEa2kBIWbHE9cCgAHgAVQxIKKgA+HlAIEWzoHgA6dbAWAHNF0QlS2ul-GegxiugQNuYRWAPJETGDpBpoFjwiNhZSC6uiVe7esoeDw2iQALb3aCgvBgqEwCbHKHgqGWMTAPD0Rp0EAQSJoAq+TYsAyBAF9AZDLA8PTnImSbzReggPCrED0LY8Il6NRAA)

Comment: Thank you this solves the original problems but please look at the edit, I made the original example too simple.

Comment: It's really bad that you put my answer to your question, because it makes it harder to understand to what I made the answer. You can just replace `cls: new () => T` with `csl: new (...args: any[]) => T`, check the update in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I did not think about that that way. Tried to correct that now. If you wish to propose what should be done instead or how the question should be edited for the better understanding of the future reader, feel free, I will consider another edit. Anyway, accepted, thank you.

Comment: I think it's better now :) Thanks!